# Understanding Rust lifetime and borrow checker

Tags: rust

Rust newbie here. Can anyone please help me understand why Rust doesn't like this code and how it can be fixed?

```
struct Foo {
    num: u32
}

struct Bar<'a> {
    foo: Foo,
    num_ref: &'a u32,
}

fn foo<'a>() -> Bar<'a> {
    let f = Foo { num: 2 };
    let n: &'a u32 = &f.num;
    return Bar { foo: f, num_ref: n };
}

fn main() { }
```

I basically want a function that returns a `Bar`, which owns `Foo` and a reference to `num` (owned by `Foo`).

[Link to playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=cac5858ebe159630d9bf328cb98aae14)

Error:

```
error[E0597]: `f.num` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:12:23
   |
12 |     let n: &'a u32 = &f.num;
   |                       ^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
13 |     return Bar { foo: f, num_ref: n };
14 | }
   | - borrowed value only lives until here
   |
note: borrowed value must be valid for the lifetime 'a as defined on the function body at 10:8...
  --> src/main.rs:10:8
   |
10 | fn foo<'a>() -> Bar<'a> {
   |        ^^
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I really do ask myself why you ever want that? You already own the variable, why do you need a reference to it? You can get it for free, you don't have to waste 8bytes for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler is saying that you are borrowing `f.num` inside the scope of the function and once this scope is done the reference to `f.num` doesn't live anymore.

I'm not sure if [this example of code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=77d76b9a6d1ed7c921d9f2036c840567) can help you, let me know. I don't know if "a reference to num" in your case is important but it doesn't seem to be necessary and maybe you didn't see how to achieve that.

I recommend you to read and take the time to understand how the [ownership system](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-00-understanding-ownership.html) works in Rust. It can be a little bit tedious at the beginning but you will master the concept with practice.